# Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?

Tags: python, string, comparison, identity, equality

Two string variables are set to the same value. `s1 == s2` always returns `True`, but `s1 is s2` sometimes returns `False`.

If I open my Python interpreter and do the same `is` comparison, it succeeds:

```
>>> s1 = 'text'
>>> s2 = 'text'
>>> s1 is s2
True
```

Why is this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-is-hello-is-hello

Comment: This problem also occurs when you read a console input via e.g.: `input = raw_input("Decide (y/n): ")`. In this case an input of "y" and `if input == 'y':`will return "True" while `if input is 'y':` will return False.

Comment: This blog provides a far more complete explanation than any answer http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Comment: As @chris-rico mentions, I great explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/1695680

Comment: can you explain specifically why in the original poster example the "is" operator fail on the script but the same operator on the same strings return "true" on the interactive mode? It's the same interpreter, so we should expect the same behaviour about interning whatever you have it run a script or run in interactive mode, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`==\` and \`is\` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: Unless you're checking that something `is None` or `is not None`, you should basically never use `is`.

Answer (score 1677, accepted):

`is` is identity testing, and `==` is equality testing. What happens in your code would be emulated in the interpreter like this:

```
>>> a = 'pub'
>>> b = ''.join(['p', 'u', 'b'])
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

So, no wonder they're not the same, right?

In other words: `a is b` is the equivalent of `id(a) == id(b)`

Comment: ahh same as eq? vs equal? in scheme, got it.

Comment: There's a lot of equality predicates in Common Lisp, besides the basic hierarchy of eq, eql, equal, and equalp (the longer the name there, the more things will be found equal).

Comment: Or `==` vs `.equals()` in Java. The best part is that the Python `==` is not analogous to the Java `==`.

Comment: And what with the `None` value?

Comment: @Крайст: there is only a single `None` value. So it always has the same id.

Comment: @SilentGhost: GvR in PEP8 says that we must never check equality and use only `is None` expression. Read about it yesterday after commented that above.

Comment: Simple, one-line test: `a = 'pub'; b = ''.join(a); a == b, a is b`

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's "is -> True" example.

Comment: why do "s2 is s1" is True in the question then?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, because of [string interning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning).

Comment: Here's an excellent [article on StackAbuse](https://stackabuse.com/comparing-strings-using-python/) explaining this and a few related matters

Comment: @pfabri: That's a *terrible* article. It includes the atrocious recommendation "A rule of thumb to follow is to use `==` when comparing immutable types (like ints) and `is` when comparing objects." You almost *never* want `is` for comparing user-defined objects. The correct rule of thumb is "Use `==` for *everything* but `None` and `NotImplemented` comparisons until you understand what you're doing." The article also fails to convey that the identity semantics of `int`s are a CPython implementation detail that only applies to small of `int`s, not some caching mechanism common to all `int`s.

Answer (score 661):

Other answers here are correct: `is` is used for *identity* comparison, while `==` is used for *equality* comparison. Since what you care about is equality (the two strings should contain the same characters), in this case the `is` operator is simply wrong and you should be using `==` instead.

The reason `is` works interactively is that (most) string literals are [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) by default. From Wikipedia:

> Interned strings speed up string
>   comparisons, which are sometimes a
>   performance bottleneck in applications
>   (such as compilers and dynamic
>   programming language runtimes) that
>   rely heavily on hash tables with
>   string keys. Without interning,
>   checking that two different strings
>   are equal involves examining every
>   character of both strings. This is
>   slow for several reasons: it is
>   inherently O(n) in the length of the
>   strings; it typically requires reads
>   from several regions of memory, which
>   take time; and the reads fills up the
>   processor cache, meaning there is less
>   cache available for other needs. With
>   interned strings, a simple object
>   identity test suffices after the
>   original intern operation; this is
>   typically implemented as a pointer
>   equality test, normally just a single
>   machine instruction with no memory
>   reference at all.

So, when you have two string literals (words that are literally typed into your program source code, surrounded by quotation marks) in your program that have the same value, the Python compiler will automatically intern the strings, making them both stored at the same memory location.  (Note that this doesn't *always* happen, and the rules for when this happens are quite convoluted, so please don't rely on this behavior in production code!)

Since in your interactive session both strings are actually stored in the same memory location, they have the same *identity*, so the `is` operator works as expected.  But if you construct a string by some other method (even if that string contains *exactly* the same characters), then the string may be *equal*, but it is not *the same string* -- that is, it has a different *identity*, because it is stored in a different place in memory.

Comment: Where can someone read more on the convoluted rules for when strings are interned?

Comment: +1 for a thorough explanation. Not sure how the other answer received so many upvotes without explaining what ACTUALLY happened.

Comment: this is exactly what I thought of when I read the question. The accepted answer is short yet contains the fact, but this answer *explains* things far better. Nice!

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Googled the same and found this http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Comment: So the general rule of thumb is to always use  `==`/`!=` when the strings are created via different methods?

Comment: @naught101: No, the rule is to choose between `==` and `is` based on what kind of check you want. If you care about the strings being *equal* (that is, having the same contents) then you should always use `==`. If you care about whether any two Python names refer to the same object instance, you should use `is`. You might need `is` if you're writing code that handles lots of different values without caring about their contents, or else if you know there is only one of something and you want to ignore other objects pretending to be that thing. If you're not sure, always chose `==`.

Comment: Does this imply that python string comparison via `==` first checks for object identity and then, failing that, for string equality?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, as a performance optimization, the CPython implementation does do an identity check first. I don't think it's guaranteed by the language spec though.

Comment: this is the bit the first answer missed, the string public was interned as an object and the two variables pointed to the same object so id(s1) is id(s2)

Comment: @jottos Perhaps this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 123):

The `is` keyword is a test for object identity while `==` is a value comparison.

If you use `is`, the result will be true if and only if the object is the same object. However, `==` will be true any time the values of the object are the same.

Answer (score 66):

One last thing to note is you may use the [`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.intern) function to ensure that you're getting a reference to the same string:

```
>>> from sys import intern
>>> a = intern('a')
>>> a2 = intern('a')
>>> a is a2
True
```

As pointed out in previous answers, you should not be using `is` to determine equality of strings.  But this may be helpful to know if you have some kind of weird requirement to use `is`.

Note that the `intern` function used to be a built-in on Python 2, but it was moved to the `sys` module in Python 3.

Answer (score 49):

`is` is identity testing and `==` is equality testing. This means `is` is a way to check whether two things are the *same* things, or just equivalent.

Say you've got a simple `person` object. If it is named 'Jack' and is '23' years old, it's equivalent to another 23-year-old Jack, but it's not the same person.

```
class Person(object):
   def __init__(self, name, age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age

   def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.name == other.name and self.age == other.age

jack1 = Person('Jack', 23)
jack2 = Person('Jack', 23)

jack1 == jack2 # True
jack1 is jack2 # False
```

They're the same age, but they're not the same instance of person. A string might be equivalent to another, but it's not the same object.

Comment: If you change set `jack1.age = 99`, that won't change `jack2.age`. That's because they are two different instances, so `jack1 is not jack2`. However, they can equal each other `jack1 == jack2` if their name and their age are the same. It gets more complicated for strings, because strings are immutable in Python, and Python often reuses the same instance. I like this explanation because it uses the simple cases (a normal object) rather then the special cases (strings).

Answer (score 40):

This is a side note, but in idiomatic Python, you will often see things like:

```
if x is None:
    # Some clauses
```

This is safe, because [there is guaranteed to be one instance of the Null Object (i.e., None)](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#the-null-object).

Comment: Is the same true for True and False?  Only one instance so is will match?

Comment: @HandyManDan Yes, they are singletons both in python 2 and 3.

Comment: @kamillitw but in Python 2 you can reassign False and True.

Answer (score 34):

If you're not sure what you're doing, use the '=='.
If you have a little more knowledge about it you can use 'is' for known objects like 'None'.

Otherwise, you'll end up wondering why things doesn't work and why this happens:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> b is a
True
>>> a = 6000
>>> b = 6000
>>> b is a
False
```

I'm not even sure if some things are guaranteed to stay the same between different Python versions/implementations.

Comment: Interesting example showing how reassigning ints makes triggers this condition.  Why did this fail?  Is it due to intern-ing or something else?

Comment: It looks like the reason the is returns false may due to the interpreter implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: Read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/pythons-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers   and    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false

Comment: @ArchitJain Yes, those links explain it pretty well. When you read them, you'll know what numbers you can use 'is' on. I just wish they would explain why it is still not a good idea to do that :) You knowing this does not make it a good idea to assume everyone else does as well (or that the internalized number range will never change)

Answer (score 26):

From my limited experience with Python, `is` is used to compare two objects to see if they are the same object as opposed to two different objects with the same value.  `==` is used to determine if the values are identical.

Here is a good example:

```
>>> s1 = u'public'
>>> s2 = 'public'
>>> s1 is s2
False
>>> s1 == s2
True
```

`s1` is a Unicode string, and `s2` is a normal string.  They are not the same type, but they are the same value.

Comment: This result is due to a different reason: comparing a unicode string (`<type 'unicode'>`) to a non-unicode string (`<type 'str'>`). It is behavior specific to Python 2. In Python 3, both of `s1` and are of type `str`, and both `is` and `==` return `True`.

Answer (score 22):

I think it has to do with the fact that, when the 'is' comparison evaluates to false, two distinct objects are used. If it evaluates to true, that means internally it's using the same exact object and not creating a new one, possibly because you created them within a fraction of 2 or so seconds and because there isn't a large time gap in between it's optimized and uses the same object.

This is why you should be using the equality operator `==`, not `is`, to compare the value of a string object.

```
>>> s = 'one'
>>> s2 = 'two'
>>> s is s2
False
>>> s2 = s2.replace('two', 'one')
>>> s2
'one'
>>> s2 is s
False
>>>
```

In this example, I made s2, which was a different string object previously equal to 'one' but it is not the same object as `s`, because the interpreter did not use the same object as I did not initially assign it to 'one', if I had it would have made them the same object.

Comment: Using `.replace()` as an example in this context is probably not the best, though, because its semantics can be confusing.  `s2 = s2.replace()` will *always* create a *new* string object, assign the new string object to `s2`, and then dispose of the string object that `s2` used to point to.  So even if you did `s = s.replace('one', 'one')` you would still get a new string object.

Answer (score 18):

The `==` operator tests value equivalence. The `is` operator tests object identity, and Python tests whether the two are really the same object (i.e., live at the same address in memory).

```
>>> a = 'banana'
>>> b = 'banana'
>>> a is b
True
```

In this example, Python only created one string object, and both `a` and `b` refers to it. The reason is that Python internally caches and reuses some strings as an optimization. There really is just a string 'banana' in memory, shared by a and b. To trigger the normal behavior, you need to use longer strings:

```
>>> a = 'a longer banana'
>>> b = 'a longer banana'
>>> a == b, a is b
(True, False)
```

When you create two lists, you get two objects:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a is b
False
```

In this case we would say that the two lists are equivalent, because they have the same elements, but not identical, because they are not the same object. If two objects are identical, they are also equivalent, but if they are equivalent, they are not necessarily identical.

If `a` refers to an object and you assign `b = a`, then both variables refer to the same object:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b is a
True
```

Reference: *[Think Python 2e](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/)* by Allen B. Downey

Comment: This is the only answer which actually explains the behavior seen, especially the part where it will sometimes work one way and sometimes another, depending on string length.  By the way, taking lower() of two strings can also switch the result from True to False.

Answer (score 17):

I believe that this is known as "interned" strings. Python does this, so does Java, and so do C and C++ when compiling in optimized modes.

If you use two identical strings, instead of wasting memory by creating two string objects, all interned strings with the same contents point to the same memory.

This results in the Python "is" operator returning True because two strings with the same contents are pointing at the same string object. This will also happen in Java and in C.

This is only useful for memory savings though. You cannot rely on it to test for string equality, because the various interpreters and compilers and JIT engines cannot always do it.

Comment: Yeah that is  the answer that i expect. OK Hari is right but how python does this. Thanks Zan, for memory optimization.

Comment: And .NET ([C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), etc.)?

Answer (score 14):

Actually, the `is` operator checks for identity and == operator checks for equality.

***From the language reference:***

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable types, operations **that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed**. E.g., after a = 1; b = 1, a and b may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the implementation, but after c = []; d = [], c and d are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists. (Note that c = d = [] assigns the same object to both c and d.)

So from the above statement we can infer that the strings, which are immutable types, may fail when checked with "is" and may succeed when checked with "is".

The same applies for `int` and `tuple` which are also immutable types.

Answer (score 7):

`is` will compare the memory location. It is used for object-level comparison.

`==` will compare the variables in the program. It is used for checking at a value level.

`is` checks for address level equivalence

`==` checks for value level equivalence

Answer (score 2):

`is` is identity testing and `==` is equality testing (see [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)).

In most cases, if `a is b`, then `a == b`. But there are exceptions, for example:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan == nan
False
```

So, you can only use `is` for identity tests, never equality tests.

Answer (score -4):

The basic concept, we have to be clear, while approaching this question, is to understand the difference between **is** and **==**.

> "is" is will compare the memory location. if id(a)==id(b), then a is b returns true else it returns false.

So, we can say that **is** is used for comparing memory locations. Whereas,

> **==** is used for equality testing which means that it just compares only the resultant values. The below shown code may acts as an example to the above given theory.

#### Code

[image: Click here for the code]

In the case of string literals (strings without getting assigned to variables), the memory address will be same as shown in the picture. so, id(a)==id(b). The remaining of this is self-explanatory.

Comment: Could you post your code directly in code tags?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65458447/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.