# How come ['hello'] is ['hello'] in Python returns False?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Why is (“hello” is “hello”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-is-hello-is-hello)

```
['hello'] is ['hello']    # gives False
```

Why? Their ids are different. Why didn't a tuple or a number end up returning False?

Answer (score 12):

Consider the following (Python 2.7.3, 64bit):

```
>>> a = "Hello"
>>> b = "Hello"
>>> a is b
True
```

Python interns the short string `'Hello'`, storing it only once. This is an implementation detail and is **not** guaranteed by the language standard. It may fail on longer strings:

```
>>> a = "this is a long string"
>>> b = "this is a long string"
>>> a is b
False
```

Now consider this:

```
>>> a = ["Hello"]
>>> b = ["Hello"]
>>> a is b
False
```

`a` and `b` are two different objects. You can check this with `id()`:

```
>>> id(a)
33826696L
>>> id(b)
33826952L
```

This is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup> because when you do

```
>>> a[0] = "Goodbye"
>>> a
['Goodbye']
>>> b
['Hello']
```

However, if you do

```
>>> a = ["Hello"]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> a[0] = "Goodbye"
>>> b
['Goodbye']
```

because `a` and `b` are names that refer to the same object (`id(a) == id(b)`). Finally, to show that even though you get

```
>>> a = ["Hello"]
>>> b = ["Hello"]
>>> a is b
False
```

the strings are still interned and stored only once:

```
>>> id(a[0])
33846096L
>>> id(b[0])
33846096L
```

Answer (score 8):

The `is` operator tests to see whether two object references refer to the same object (it is not an equality operator, but an identity operator). In your example you have created two separate lists, therefore you have two different objects, which is why you see `False` being returned.

Comment: Excellent. But how do I guarantee the name refers to that same object? In other words, how can I ensure that kind of optimization is on for my object? Why can't Python realize `['hello']` is done twice?

Comment: Try assigning your lists to variables, that might make things clearer: l=['hello'] l is l will return True, l=['hello'] m=['hello'] l is m will return False

Comment: If you do `a = ['hello']; b = ['hello']`, `a is b` will be False because it's two different objects. After all, you wouldn't want `a[0] = "Goodbye"` to affect `b`, would you? If you do  `a = ['hello']; b = a`, however, `a is b` will be True, and `a[0] = "Goodbye"` will affect `b`, too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker So is mutable obejct causing Python not to optimize it (as a policy decision)?

Comment: There is nothing to optimize - you have two different, independent objects. The string `'hello'` *is*  optimized by interning, so it's only stored once. But your `is` comparison doesn't compare the strings, it compares the lists!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a list using the `[]` syntax, a new list object is created. Lists are mutable objects and thus, even if two lists happen to contain the same elements, they are not the same objects. You can observe that changing a list by calling one of its modifying methods does in fact not change the ID:

```
In [1]: a = ["hello"]
In [2]: b = ["hello"]
In [3]: id(a)
Out[3]: 4477468112
In [4]: id(b)
Out[4]: 4477467824
In [5]: a.append("world")
In [6]: id(a)
Out[6]: 4477468112
```

Comment: `"For immutable objects, for example strings, different variables will in fact refer to the same object"` that's not correct. See Tim Pietzcker's answer on this.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint. I deleted that part.