# Check if a character equals quotes in python

Tags: python

I am iterating through a string in python and I want to check each character to see if it equals `"`.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
for c in theString:
    if c == '"':
        print 'Aha!'
```

You can also directly get the index of the first quote like so:

```
theString.index('"')
```

Comment: Note that this is probably best replaced with `if '"' in some_string: ...` (unless you are already looping through the string for other purposes or some such).

Comment: @Lattyware: Absolutely, if the goal is merely to check if there is a quote at all.

Comment: Naturally, it depends on the goal.

Comment: Note: there is a modest performance advantage using `if c is '"':`

Comment: @Eric: Good point, [but be careful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1392927/21475) as that's an implementation detail, not a guarantee of the language.