# Why is this iteration not updating the count?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes two strings as parameters, turns them in lists, and then returns an index of where the two strings differ:

```
def ss(line1,line2):
    count = 0
    list1 = line1.split()
    list2 = line2.split()
    for word in list1:
        if word is not list2[count]:
            return count
        else:
            count += 1

ss("Why is this not working?", "Why is this not working?")
```

The output I get is that my count is whatever I set it to initially (e.g., "0"). As far as I can see, it should be updating the count and then reiterating through the lists to compare the next indexes?

What do I not understand about how for-loops work?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `!=` instead of `is not`.

**Explanation**:

- The `is` keyword in Python compares object identity. Every string in Python is it's own separate object and thus, it's own separate identity. So when you use the `is` keyword with two strings it will not check the actual contents.
- However, to compare the contents of an object or variable you can use `==` or `!=` which return True or False.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: It's not *quite* that simple: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392440/9200529). But of course your suggestion is exactly right. +1

Comment: Funnily enough I noticed that when testing some code that I initially included. Thanks for providing the clarification.