# __repr__ method and repr() on a list return different objects

Tags: python

Say that we have a list `my_num=[1,2,3,4,5]`.
 Applying `repr()` on that list returns a representation of this object as a string, say `a=repr(my_num)`. I thought that calling `my_num.__repr__()` would yield the same object.

However:

```
>>> my_num=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a=repr(my_num)
>>> a is my_num.__repr__()
False
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What about `a = my_num.__repr__()`? `my_num.__repr__` is a function, actually is the function that is called when you do `repr(my_num)`

Comment: I tried that too, didn't work. In fact I changed my question and included the parenthesis.

Comment: Also `is` is for checking identity, not equality

Comment: yeah strictly speaking you're right. I'm talking about the underlying structure of these two objects.

Comment: Both are strings that have the same value, but they are not the same string

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, each call returns a string image of `my_num`.  Python will fold small integers, but not a string of any complexity.  Each call returns a *separate* string object, so they have different id values.

`is` compares id's; `==` compares values.

```
>>> my_num=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> repr(my_num)
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
>>> a = repr(my_num)
>>> id(a)
139786829689392
>>> a
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
>>> b = my_num.__repr__()
>>> b
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
>>> id(b)
139786829689264
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(repr(my_num))
140357224404912
>>> id(my_num.__repr__())
140357224404976
>>> repr(my_num) == my_num.__repr__()
True
```

As you can see `id` is different (i.e. these are different objects), but they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between [equality and identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is).
using `repr(obj)` and `obj.__repr__()` is the same, however the `repr` function creates a new string object, and hence the two objects that are created are not identical.

You can even see that:

```
>>> my_num=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> my_num.__repr__() is my_num.__repr__()
False
```

Check these for more info:

[Python: Why does ("hello" is "hello") evaluate as True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-does-hello-is-hello-evaluate-as-true)

[Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)