# Python Strings: is vs ==

Tags: python

I had an interesting problem today.

```
def get_tag_by_name(a_dict, key):
    return a_dict.get(key, "")

record={"key": "-1"}
print(get_tag_by_name(record, "key") is "-1")
print(get_tag_by_name(record, "key") == "-1")

Returns:
False
True
```

Now I do understand that:

```
is will compare the memory location. It is used for object-level comparison.
== will compare the variables in the program. It is used for checking at a value level.
is checks for address level equivalence
== checks for value level equivalence
```

What I do not understand is, why is the dictionary.get(key,"") creating a new object when the string is "-1" vs "test"

```
>>> def get_tag_by_name(a_dict, key):
...     return a_dict.get(key, "")
...
>>> record={"num_key": "-1", "str_key": "test"}
>>> print(get_tag_by_name(record, "num_key") is "-1", get_tag_by_name(record, "num_key") == "-1")
False True
>>> print(get_tag_by_name(record, "str_key") is "test", get_tag_by_name(record, "str_key") == "test")
True True
>>>
```

Already consulted:

1. [Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)
2. [Python: Why does ("hello" is "hello") evaluate as True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-does-hello-is-hello-evaluate-as-true)
3. [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)