# Python: Throw ERROR on maxing out a time constant

Tags: python, profiling

I've seen this post on using Timer:

[Accurate timing of functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889900/accurate-timing-of-functions-in-python)

And while it does get the time for a known operation... I need something slightly different.

I want:

1. execute a function + start a timer
2. allow function to run
3. if function completes < X milliseconds: no error
4. if function completes >=X milliseconds: ERROR "expected time constant exceeded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate your request almost directly into code -- simply add an "if" statement, and throw an exception:

```
import timeit

def test(operation, setup, threshold):
    # Add any kind of timing setup here.
    t = timeit.Timer(operation, setup=setup)

    # Note: t.timeit(number=1) returns the time in seconds, not milliseconds
    if t.timeit() > threshold:
        raise Exception("ERROR: expected time constant exceeded")
```

Comment: Would this work? From what I understand about Timer ... the t = timeit.Timer() statement will only return post completion of "operation" ... thus it won't event an error DURING "operation" but instead post execution of "operation" ... right?

Comment: @delinquentme - oh, I think see what you mean. Rather then simply measuring how long a function takes to run, you want to stop it immediately when it crosses some threshold, right? Is this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/646543) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/646543) closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: The links above covered exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To throw an error use:

```
raise Exception("my message")
```

(works at Python 2.7, I'm not sure about 3)

So in your function:

```
if time >= expected: raise Exception("took too long!")
```

You can also have your own error class:

```
class TooLongError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

raise TooLongError("took too long")
```

Produces:

> TooLongError: took too long

Comment: Like the answer below, this would raise an exception only after completion of the Timed operation.  I need an error EVENT within the operation being run... A running timer, which doesn't wait for the completion of the method being timed