# How to compute the time that a machine learning model take to classify?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to compute the time that a machine learning model takes to process to classify the data.
I am using scikit-learn. I can compute the accuracy, the recall and the precision by using:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
.....
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
y_pred = model.predict(Xtest)
print(accuracy_score(Ytest, y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(Ytest, y_pred))
print(classification_report(Ytest, y_pred))
```

But I do not know how to compute the evaluation time of the classification. Is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accurate timing of functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889900/accurate-timing-of-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
fit_classifier()
print(time() - t0)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use something like that:

```
import time
.....
start = time.time()
y_pred = model.predict(Xtest)
end = time.time()
eval_time = end-start # in seconds
```

Just wrap the part of code you want to inspect with `start = ...` and `end = ...`